# Modify existing YAML values using Gulp

Tags: gulp, yaml

I'm pretty new to `YAML` and I feel like I missing something or making my own life harder than it should be.

I'm using [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) to run a bunch of tasks to minify CSS/JS and lint my code, but for the final build I need to modify a `YAML` file that contains some configuration values.

This is part of my `YAML` file:

```
- adx_name: RedirectUri
  adx_sitesettingid: 3745e5fe-2b95-eb11-b1ac-000d3a2cd507
  adx_value: https://example.com/signin
```

The YAML file contains a bunch of config but I just need to change the `adx_value` where `adx_name` = `RedirectUri`.

I don't seem to be able to find any `Gulp` plugins that work with `YAML` directly, other than those that are able to read `YAML` or append to `YAML` files. What I need to be able to do it edit the file and write new values at the correct location in the file.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Red2678 Not yet :(

Comment: Bummer. *sad noises*

Comment: Have you tried [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) with `--inplace` flag? I'm not familiar with `gulp` but I suppose it can run CLI commands - right?

Comment: @Red2678 A solution has been posted, uses gulp-replace and for my basic use case it works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace).

```js
gulp.task('yaml-replace', function () {
  return gulp.src('./test.yaml')
    .pipe(replace(/(?<=adx_name:\s)(RedirectUri)/g, 'myReplacement'))  // positive lookbehind
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./yaml'));
});
```

The replace function can take a string or regex and replace with a string or function.

Result:

```yaml
- adx_name: myReplacement
  adx_sitesettingid: 3745e5fe-2b95-eb11-b1ac-000d3a2cd507
  adx_value: https://example.com/signin
```